# Django FileField - missed upload_to while save()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model with field

```
class ExampleObject(model.Model):
   logo = models.FileField(upload_to="topics/")
```

When I want to save a file by Command using ExampleObject's save() method:

```
topic.logo.save(
   "filename.svg",
    File(open(path_to_file))
)
```

it saves files in `topics/` folder, but when I want to open it I get the following error:

> No such file or directory: /path/to/file/without/upload_to/filename.svg

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is properly saved in the filesystem, and make sure to config MEDIA_ROOT

take a look to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for help! But I figured it out. I didn't fix it by .save() method but I put uploading file inside creating method and it removed my problem.